# VueJS routes with component tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

Whenever I use the component tag  which has an id of #app within the template inside my components/App.vue it returns the following errors:

```
// components/App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img class="logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <hello></hello>
    <a v-link="{ path: '/home' }">Go to Foo</a>
    <a v-link="{ path: '/about' }">Go to Bar</a>
    <p>
      Welcome to your Vue.js app!
    </p>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Errors

```
[vue-router] <router-view> can only be used inside a router-enabled app.

[vue-router] v-link can only be used inside a router-enabled app.
```

However, if do it like this without the component and just a regular element with the component id it works normally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>VueJS Starter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to use router with web components? Because having to use it with an element id also does not work with vue-devtools in Chrome.

Comment: I think you're possibly used to something like Backbone or Ractive where the JS parses the template and then inserts the rendered content INTO a place holder. In the top-most VueJS, you use an element ID to mount the entire application. But each ROUTED component within that is slotted into the correct place in the router-view hierarchy. 

What you appear to be trying to do is to mount your app WITHIN a template of something else (or perhaps Vue itself, I'm not sure), but this isn't how its' done. Suggest another pass at the docs. http://vuejs.org/guide/index.html

Comment: This problem has to do with how you have set up your application. We have to see your main js file to see how you bootstrapped the components.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to provide the information at your `main.js` file.

There you should properly import and use the router, like this:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
...
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```